# Lookup and replace each element in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have this array, with its first column as an id:

```
var mainarray = [
["1001","P6","P8"],
["1002","P7"],
["1003","P7","P8","P10"],
["1004","P6","P10"],
];
```

I want to replace each 'P' element with its corresponding animal from the 'lookup' array below:

```
var arraylookup= [
["P6","dog"],
["P7","cat"],
["P8","mouse"],
["P9","horse"],
["P10","cow"],
];
```

... which will give me the following new array

```
var newarray= [
["1001","dog","mouse"],
["1002","cat"],
["1003","cat","mouse","cow"],
["1004","dog","cow"],
];
```

I've managed to confuse myself totally on this one.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: That `arraylookup` data format is _horrible_ to work with. Can you modify that object? A significantly simpler option would be something like: `{"P6":"dog","P7":"cat"}`...

Comment: Oh, this probably explains why I haven't been able to get anything to work yet.  Yes, it can be modified to your suggestion.

Comment: I'm sure there are reasons but I don't see the point of the downvotes.  I'm trying to learn here which I thought that was the point of SO.  I didn't submit any attempts because I had nothing of value to show.  Not a complaint, just an observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your `mainarray` to map the items in the entries to their looked-up values.

To easily lookup a value, create a map like this:

```
const lookup = {
  P6: "dog",
  P7: "cat",
  P8: "mouse",
  P9: "horse",
  P10: "cow"
};
```

You can generate this from your `arraylookup` array using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Or simply reformat `arraylookup` to an object in your code.

You can use destructuring to extract the items from the array entries.

```js
const arr = [
  ["1001","P6","P8"],
  ["1002","P7"],
  ["1003","P7","P8","P10"],
  ["1004","P6","P10"],
];
const arrLookup = [
  ["P6","dog"],
  ["P7","cat"],
  ["P8","mouse"],
  ["P9","horse"],
  ["P10","cow"],
];

const lookup = arrLookup.reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: v }), {});

const result = arr.map(([id, ...rest]) => [id, ...rest.map(x => lookup[x])]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should convert `arraylookup` into an object i.e:

```
const objLookUp= {
  "P6": "dog"],
  "P7": "cat",
  ...
};
```

```js
const arrayLookUp= [
  ["P6","dog"],
  ["P7","cat"],
  ["P8","mouse"],
  ["P9","horse"],
  ["P10","cow"],
];

const objLookUp = arrayLookUp.reduce((r, [key, value]) => (r[key]= value, r), {});

console.log(objLookUp);
```

Then it will be much easier for you to transform the input array into desired format:

```js
const mainArray = [
  ["1001","P6","P8"],
  ["1002","P7"],
  ["1003","P7","P8","P10"],
  ["1004","P6","P10"],
];

const arrayLookUp= [
  ["P6","dog"],
  ["P7","cat"],
  ["P8","mouse"],
  ["P9","horse"],
  ["P10","cow"],
];

const objLookUp = arrayLookUp.reduce((r, [key, value]) => (r[key]= value, r), {});
const result = mainArray.map(
  arr => arr.map(v => v in objLookUp ? objLookUp[v] : v)
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find` and `map` with `startsWith` like so:

```js
const array = [
  ["1001","P6","P8"],
  ["1002","P7"],
  ["1003","P7","P8","P10"],
  ["1004","P6","P10"],
];
const lookup = [
  ["P6","dog"],
  ["P7","cat"],
  ["P8","mouse"],
  ["P9","horse"],
  ["P10","cow"],
];

const result = array.map(arr => {
  let replaced = arr.map(s => {
    if (s.startsWith("P")) {
      var newValue = lookup.find(a => a[0] == s)[1];
      return newValue;
    }
    return s;
  });
  return replaced;
});

console.log(result);
```

ES5 equivalent:

```js
var array = [
  ["1001", "P6", "P8"],
  ["1002", "P7"],
  ["1003", "P7", "P8", "P10"],
  ["1004", "P6", "P10"],
];
var lookup = [
  ["P6", "dog"],
  ["P7", "cat"],
  ["P8", "mouse"],
  ["P9", "horse"],
  ["P10", "cow"],
];

var result = array.map(function(arr) {
  var replaced = arr.map(function(s) {
      if (s.startsWith("P")) {
        var newValue = lookup.find(function(a) {
            return a[0] == s;
        })[1];
      return newValue;
    }
    return s;
  });
return replaced;
});

console.log(result);
```